# Get current clicked element id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible to get current input element id by click function from multiple input field all of input field has same class name but id's are unique.
Like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id=chkBox1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id=chkBox2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id=chkBox3" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id=chkBox4" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id=chkBox5" value="5" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#chkBox1').on('change', function() {
      $('input#chkBox1').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });
  });
</script>
```

but its work for chkbox1. not working on onclick event fire for any input field.

Comment: Do you need this kind of answer http://jsfiddle.net/z9wkLsa0/6/

Answer (score 1):

There is issue in html use  `id="chkBox1"` inseted of `id=chkBox1"`

### html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id="chkBox1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id="chkBox2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id="chkBox3" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id="chkBox4" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" class="chkTag" id="chkBox5" value="5" />
```

### JS

```
$('input[type=checkbox].chkTag').on('change', function() {
     alert(this.id)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chkTag').on('change', function() {
      alert( $(this).prop('id') );  
    });
  });
</script>
```